# Grouping two column data using group by clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want query which will display only one data from one id

My query is

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE sender_id='$memberid'
  AND reciver_id IN($frens)
  OR reciver_id='$memberid'
  AND senderid IN($frens)
GROUP BY sender_id,
         reciever_id
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

This query is displaying separate value for both columns.

Suppose I have 48 as memberid and it is present in both columns it is displaying 48 two times n I want it one time only.

Please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing an underscore in "AND senderid IN($frens)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not PHP guy though.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE (sender_id='$memberid' AND reciver_id IN($frens))
  OR (reciver_id='$memberid' AND sender_id IN($frenss))
GROUP BY sender_id
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

I just wonder why you have return select *, & how you are not getting any errors.
I just followed your code & added () around conditions.

Comment: I think because you are grouping by 2 columns, you are nit getting desired result.Please see my updated ans.

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis to group/prioritize your filter options.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE (sender_id='$memberid'  <-- added an open parenthesis
 AND reciver_id IN($frens))  <-- added a close parentheis
 OR (reciver_id='$memberid'  <-- added an open parenthesis
 AND sender_id IN($frens))    <-- added a close parentheis    
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

I removed `group by` clause since your select don't have an aggregate function.